# The RWPickFlavor.podspec specification does not validate

Tags: ios, swift, git, github, cocoapods

I'm learning by following this tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift

And I'm stuck in the place where it says:
Using Your New CocoaPod

in the terminal I wrote:

```
cd ~/Documents/Libraries/RWPickFlavor 
pod repo add RWPodSpecs https://github.com/user/RWPodSpecs.git 
pod repo push RWPodSpecs RWPickFlavor.podspec
```

but I get a lot of errors:

```
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/user/RWPodSpecs.git -- RWPodSpecs

fatal: destination path 'RWPodSpecs' already exists and is not an empty directory
```

and:

```
Validating spec
 -> RWPickFlavor (0.1.0)
    - NOTE  | url: The URL (https://github.com/user/RWPickFlavor) is not reachable.
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error ([!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/user/RWPickFlavor.git /var/folders/bw/h527d_4x6yb7rv3tdrldty1c0000gn/T/d20220525-6530-de485a --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.1.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/bw/h527d_4x6yb7rv3tdrldty1c0000gn/T/d20220525-6530-de485a'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 0.1.0 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 0.1.0 not found in upstream origin
) during validation.

[!] The `RWPickFlavor.podspec` specification does not validate.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess that it's not the real URL `https://github.com/user/RWPodSpecs.git`, that it's your own git repo, right? Also, did you put a tag `0.1.0` on your repo?

Comment: In this post, I have only replaced my real user with the generic word user, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Yes my repository has the 0.1.0 tag

Comment: Is it a public repo? Because if it isn't then, CocoaPods won't be able to reach it, which could explaine the URL issue

Comment: Yes they are public

Answer (score 1):

I had this very issue and here is how I resolved it:

1. Verify you are in the `~/Documents/Libraries/RWPickFlavor` directory before performing any commands in Terminal.
2. Verify that the contents of `RWPickFlavor.podspec` are correct. Mine was not and, if something is wrong, then it will not validate the Podspec.
3. I went ahead and deleted the remote repository on GitHub and then ran `rm -rf .git` (again, make sure you are in `~/Documents/Libraries/RWPickFlavor`). This step might be excessive, but I figured I had missed something when pushing to GitHub and, since this was just an initial commit, I did not feel like it really harmed anything. Yes, I am aware this is not best practice with regards to version control.
4. I then went ahead and recreated the remote repository on GitHub.
5. With the remote repository once again available, I did the following:

   - `git init`
   - `git add .`
   - `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
   - `git tag 0.1.0`
   - `git branch -M main`
   - `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/RWPickFlavor.git`
   - `git push -u origin main --tags`
   - `pod repo push RWPodSpecs RWPickFlavor.podspec`

Explanation: I think I/we might have forgotten the tag creation in the process and also forgot to include it in the push. Before I deleted the remote repo, I noticed that there was no tag and, even if I added a tag, the Podspec still would not validate.

Hope this is helpful.